# Compare quantity of two lists - with a given tolerance

Tags: c#, list

I want to compare two lists, which both can be null, both can contain `0` or more entries.

If the amount matches, there should be some handling for that.
If not, it should be checked if the difference of the amount is covered by the tolerance given.

Here's what I did. Is there a more elegant way to do that?

```
int tolerableDifference = 5; //example.                
Result success = Result.Valid;

if (listA.Count == listB.Count)
{
  // do whatever is to be done when counts match. 
}
else
{
    // Lists have different length. No match.
    var absDifference = Math.Abs(listA.Count - listB.Count);

    if ((listA.Count - listB.Count) > 0)
    {
        if (absDifference < tolerableDifference)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Difference below Tolerance threshold. Difference: {absDifference}.");
        }
        else
        {
            //Outside tolerance, too less items in listB
            success = Result.Invalid | Result.TooFewItems;
        }
    }
    else if ((listA.Count - listB.Count) < 0)
    {
        if (absDifference < tolerableDifference)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Difference below Tolerance threshold. Difference: {absDifference}.");
        }
        else
        {
            //Outside tolerance, too many items in listB
            success = Result.Invalid | Result.TooManyItems;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't check for `null`, BTW.

Comment: I have a feeling that your question might be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks, dymanoid, you're right. that snipplet is taken from the code, excluding the null-check.

Comment: "More elegant" is quite opinion-based, isn´t it? Voting to close. You should consider to post this question on codereview.

Comment: thanks, i'll do that!

Comment: thanks :) put on hold as off-topic by t3chb0t, Toby Speight, πάντα ῥεῖ, tinstaafl, Heslacher 3 hours ago
This question appears to be off-topic for this site. While what’s on- and off-topic is not always intuitive, you can learn more about it by reading the help center. The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this ?

```
int tolerableDifference = 5; //example.                
Result success = Result.Valid;

var countA = listA == null?0:listA.Count;
var countB = listB == null?0:listB.Count;

if(coutA == countB)
{
  // do whatever is to be done when counts match. 
}
else
{
    var diff = countA - countB;
    var absDiff = Math.Abs(diff);
    if(absDiff < tolerableDifference)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Difference below Tolerance threshold. Difference: {absDiff}.");
    }
    else
    {
        success = Result.Invalid | (diff>0?Result.TooFewItems:Result.TooManyItems);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I love the new switch-enhancements introduced in C# 7:

```
  switch (listA.Count - listB.Count)
  {
    case 0:
      // do whatever
      break;

    case int n when n > 0 && n < tolerableDifference:
      Console.WriteLine($"Difference below Tolerance threshold. Difference: {n}.");
      break;

    case int n when n >= tolerableDifference:
      success = Result.Invalid | Result.TooManyItems;
      break;

    case int n when n < 0 && n > -tolerableDifference:
      Console.WriteLine($"Difference below Tolerance threshold. Difference: {-n}.");
      break;

    case int n when n <= -tolerableDifference:
      success = Result.Invalid | Result.TooFewItems;
      break;

  }
```

Comment: I like it too, yes! Unfortunately our Build Server is not yet updated to C#7, so i cannot use that :(

Comment: c#7 is not too young, but rather standard today. you should tell your admin and devops to update the build server ! :-)